# Unable to open sonar in browser

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

Installed sonarqube and started the sonar service. but sonar is not opening in the browser with port 9000. havent done any changes in sonar.properties file (all the contents are commented). but the log shows the web server is started, http connector enabled port on 9000. how it is possible when contents are commented?

port status

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9000                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
```

Sonar logs

```
<-- Wrapper Stopped
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2015.09.22 10:09:31 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[search]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.85.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/sonarqube-5.1.2/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /tmp/sq-process7377450394324020959properties
2015.09.22 10:09:32 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting search
2015.09.22 10:09:32 INFO   es[o.s.s.SearchServer]  Starting Elasticsearch[sonarqube] on port 9001
2015.09.22 10:09:32 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1442930970839] version[1.4.4], pid[27953], build[c88f77f/2015-02-19T13:05:36Z]
2015.09.22 10:09:32 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1442930970839] initializing ...
2015.09.22 10:09:32 INFO   es[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1442930970839] loaded [], sites []
2015.09.22 10:09:35 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1442930970839] initialized
2015.09.22 10:09:35 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1442930970839] starting ...
2015.09.22 10:09:35 INFO   es[o.e.transport]  [sonar-1442930970839] bound_address {inet[/0.0.0.0:9001]}, publish_address {inet[/10.246.236.55:9001]}
2015.09.22 10:09:35 INFO   es[o.e.discovery]  [sonar-1442930970839] sonarqube/xTJRTzNESlunLbRSr4pkYA
2015.09.22 10:09:38 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.service]  [sonar-1442930970839] new_master [sonar-1442930970839][xTJRTzNESlunLbRSr4pkYA][usboss-sdijenkins.aaitg.com][inet[/10.246.236.55:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1442930970839}, reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
2015.09.22 10:09:38 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1442930970839] started
2015.09.22 10:09:40 INFO   es[o.e.gateway]  [sonar-1442930970839] recovered [6] indices into cluster_state
2015.09.22 10:09:41 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[search] is up
2015.09.22 10:09:41 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.85.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/sonarqube-5.1.2/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/usr/local/sonarqube-5.1.2/lib/jdbc/h2/h2-1.3.176.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /tmp/sq-process4883903207582149281properties
2015.09.22 10:09:42 INFO  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2015.09.22 10:09:42 INFO  web[o.s.s.app.Webapp] Webapp directory: /usr/local/sonarqube-5.1.2/web
2015.09.22 10:09:43 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2015.09.22 10:09:43 INFO  web[o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2015.09.22 10:09:44 INFO  web[o.e.plugins] [sonar-1442930970839] loaded [], sites []
2015.09.22 10:09:45 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl] SonarQube Server / 5.1.2 / 2a52a7106b2bfbd659c591c2d6fc09ad0ab2db5c
2015.09.22 10:09:46 INFO  web[o.s.s.d.EmbeddedDatabase] Starting embedded database on port 9092 with url jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar
2015.09.22 10:09:46 INFO  web[o.s.s.d.EmbeddedDatabase] Embedded database started. Data stored in: /usr/local/sonarqube-5.1.2/data
2015.09.22 10:09:46 INFO  web[o.s.c.p.Database] Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar
2015.09.22 10:09:47 WARN  web[o.s.s.d.DatabaseChecker] H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only
2015.09.22 10:09:49 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem] SonarQube home: /usr/local/sonarqube-5.1.2
2015.09.22 10:09:49 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Install plugins
2015.09.22 10:09:49 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin Git / 1.0 / 9ce9d330c313c296fab051317cc5ad4b26319e07
2015.09.22 10:09:49 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin SVN / 1.0 / 213fc8a8b582ff530b12dd4a59a6512be1071234
2015.09.22 10:09:49 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin Core / 5.1.2 / 2a52a7106b2bfbd659c591c2d6fc09ad0ab2db5c
2015.09.22 10:09:49 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin Java / 3.0 / 65396a609ddface8b311a6a665aca92a7da694f1
2015.09.22 10:09:49 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin English Pack / 5.1.2 / 2a52a7106b2bfbd659c591c2d6fc09ad0ab2db5c
2015.09.22 10:09:49 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin Email notifications / 5.1.2 / 2a52a7106b2bfbd659c591c2d6fc09ad0ab2db5c
2015.09.22 10:09:49 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.RailsAppsDeployer] Deploy Ruby on Rails applications
2015.09.22 10:09:49 INFO  web[o.s.j.s.AbstractDatabaseConnector] Initializing Hibernate
2015.09.22 10:09:50 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.UpdateCenterClient] Update center: http://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (no proxy)
2015.09.22 10:09:51 INFO  web[o.s.s.n.NotificationService] Notification service started (delay 60 sec.)
2015.09.22 10:09:52 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer] Index rules
2015.09.22 10:09:52 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer] Index activeRules
2015.09.22 10:09:52 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics] Register metrics
2015.09.22 10:09:53 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics] Cleaning quality gate conditions
2015.09.22 10:09:53 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterDebtModel] Register technical debt model
2015.09.22 10:09:53 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Register rules
2015.09.22 10:09:54 INFO  web[o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Register quality profiles
2015.09.22 10:09:55 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterNewMeasureFilters] Register measure filters
2015.09.22 10:09:55 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterDashboards] Register dashboards
2015.09.22 10:09:55 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterPermissionTemplates] Register permission templates
2015.09.22 10:09:55 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RenameDeprecatedPropertyKeys] Rename deprecated property keys
2015.09.22 10:09:55 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer] Index activities
2015.09.22 10:09:55 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer] Index issues
2015.09.22 10:09:55 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer] Index source lines
2015.09.22 10:09:55 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer] Index users
2015.09.22 10:09:55 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer] Index views
2015.09.22 10:09:55 INFO  web[jruby.rack] jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-12-06 87b108a on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_85-mockbuild_2015_07_25_13_10-b00 [linux-amd64]
2015.09.22 10:09:55 INFO  web[jruby.rack] using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
2015.09.22 10:10:26 INFO  web[jruby.rack] keeping custom (config.logger) Rails logger instance
2015.09.22 10:10:26 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2015.09.22 10:10:26 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
2015.09.22 10:10:26 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2015.09.22 10:10:27 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is up
```

sonar.properties file

```
# See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)
#
# Property values can:
# - reference an environment variable, for example sonar.jdbc.url= ${env:SONAR_JDBC_URL}
# - be encrypted. See http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/settings-encryption.html


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# DATABASE
#
# IMPORTANT: the embedded H2 database is used by default. It is recommended for tests but not for
# production use. Supported databases are MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL and Microsoft SQLServer.

# User credentials.
# Permissions to create tables, indices and triggers must be granted to JDBC user.
# The schema must be created first.
#sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
#sonar.jdbc.password=sonar

#----- Embedded Database (default)
# It does not accept connections from remote hosts, so the
# server and the analyzers must be executed on the same host.
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar

# H2 embedded database server listening port, defaults to 9092
#sonar.embeddedDatabase.port=9092


#----- MySQL 5.x
# Only InnoDB storage engine is supported (not myISAM).
# Only the bundled driver is supported.
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance


#----- Oracle 10g/11g
# - Only thin client is supported
# - Only versions 11.2.* of Oracle JDBC driver are supported, even if connecting to lower Oracle versions.
# - The JDBC driver must be copied into the directory extensions/jdbc-driver/oracle/
# - If you need to set the schema, please refer to http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5000
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost/XE


#----- PostgreSQL 8.x/9.x
# If you don't use the schema named "public", please refer to http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5000
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar


#----- Microsoft SQLServer 2008/2012
# Only the bundled jTDS driver is supported.
# Collation must be case-sensitive (CS) and accent-sensitive (AS).
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/sonar;SelectMethod=Cursor


#----- Connection pool settings
# The maximum number of active connections that can be allocated
# at the same time, or negative for no limit.
#sonar.jdbc.maxActive=50

# The maximum number of connections that can remain idle in the
# pool, without extra ones being released, or negative for no limit.
#sonar.jdbc.maxIdle=5

# The minimum number of connections that can remain idle in the pool,
# without extra ones being created, or zero to create none.
#sonar.jdbc.minIdle=2

# The maximum number of milliseconds that the pool will wait (when there
# are no available connections) for a connection to be returned before
# throwing an exception, or <= 0 to wait indefinitely.
#sonar.jdbc.maxWait=5000

#sonar.jdbc.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=600000
#sonar.jdbc.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=30000



#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# WEB SERVER

# Web server is executed in a dedicated Java process. By default heap size is 768Mb.
# Use the following property to customize JVM options.
#    Recommendations:
#
#    The HotSpot Server VM is recommended. The property -server should be added if server mode
#    is not enabled by default on your environment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html
#
#    Set min and max memory (respectively -Xms and -Xmx) to the same value to prevent heap
#    from resizing at runtime.
#
#sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

# Same as previous property, but allows to not repeat all other settings like -Xmx
#sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts=

# Binding IP address. For servers with more than one IP address, this property specifies which
# address will be used for listening on the specified ports.
# By default, ports will be used on all IP addresses associated with the server.
#sonar.web.host=0.0.0.0
#sonar.web.host=localhost
# Web context. When set, it must start with forward slash (for example /sonarqube).
# The default value is root context (empty value).
#sonar.web.context=

# TCP port for incoming HTTP connections. Disabled when value is -1.
#sonar.web.port=9000


# Recommendation for HTTPS
#    SonarQube natively supports HTTPS. However using a reverse proxy
#    infrastructure is the recommended way to set up your SonarQube installation
#    on production environments which need to be highly secured.
#    This allows to fully master all the security parameters that you want.

# TCP port for incoming HTTPS connections. Disabled when value is -1 (default).
#sonar.web.https.port=-1

# HTTPS - the alias used to for the server certificate in the keystore.
# If not specified the first key read in the keystore is used.
#sonar.web.https.keyAlias=

# HTTPS - the password used to access the server certificate from the
# specified keystore file. The default value is "changeit".
#sonar.web.https.keyPass=changeit

# HTTPS - the pathname of the keystore file where is stored the server certificate.
# By default, the pathname is the file ".keystore" in the user home.
# If keystoreType doesn't need a file use empty value.
#sonar.web.https.keystoreFile=

# HTTPS - the password used to access the specified keystore file. The default
# value is the value of sonar.web.https.keyPass.
#sonar.web.https.keystorePass=

# HTTPS - the type of keystore file to be used for the server certificate.
# The default value is JKS (Java KeyStore).
#sonar.web.https.keystoreType=JKS

# HTTPS - the name of the keystore provider to be used for the server certificate.
# If not specified, the list of registered providers is traversed in preference order
# and the first provider that supports the keystore type is used (see sonar.web.https.keystoreType).
#sonar.web.https.keystoreProvider=

# HTTPS - the pathname of the truststore file which contains trusted certificate authorities.
# By default, this would be the cacerts file in your JRE.
# If truststoreFile doesn't need a file use empty value.
#sonar.web.https.truststoreFile=

# HTTPS - the password used to access the specified truststore file.
#sonar.web.https.truststorePass=

# HTTPS - the type of truststore file to be used.
# The default value is JKS (Java KeyStore).
#sonar.web.https.truststoreType=JKS

# HTTPS - the name of the truststore provider to be used for the server certificate.
# If not specified, the list of registered providers is traversed in preference order
# and the first provider that supports the truststore type is used (see sonar.web.https.truststoreType).
#sonar.web.https.truststoreProvider=

# HTTPS - whether to enable client certificate authentication.
# The default is false (client certificates disabled).
# Other possible values are 'want' (certificates will be requested, but not required),
# and 'true' (certificates are required).
#sonar.web.https.clientAuth=false

# HTTPS - comma separated list of encryption ciphers to support for HTTPS connections.
# If specified, only the ciphers that are listed and supported by the SSL implementation will be used.
# By default, the default ciphers for the JVM will be used. Note that this usually means that the weak
# export grade ciphers, for instance RC4, will be included in the list of available ciphers.
# The ciphers are specified using the JSSE cipher naming convention (see
# https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html)
# Example: sonar.web.https.ciphers=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
#sonar.web.https.ciphers=

# The maximum number of connections that the server will accept and process at any given time.
# When this number has been reached, the server will not accept any more connections until
# the number of connections falls below this value. The operating system may still accept connections
# based on the sonar.web.connections.acceptCount property. The default value is 50 for each
# enabled connector.
#sonar.web.http.maxThreads=50
#sonar.web.https.maxThreads=50

# The minimum number of threads always kept running. The default value is 5 for each
# enabled connector.
#sonar.web.http.minThreads=5
#sonar.web.https.minThreads=5

# The maximum queue length for incoming connection requests when all possible request processing
# threads are in use. Any requests received when the queue is full will be refused.
# The default value is 25 for each enabled connector.
#sonar.web.http.acceptCount=25
#sonar.web.https.acceptCount=25

# TCP port for incoming AJP connections. Disabled if value is -1. Disabled by default.
#sonar.ajp.port=-1


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ELASTICSEARCH
# Elasticsearch is used to facilitate fast and accurate information retrieval.
# It is executed in a dedicated Java process.

# JVM options of Elasticsearch process
#    Recommendations:
#
#    Use HotSpot Server VM. The property -server should be added if server mode
#    is not enabled by default on your environment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html
#
#    Set min and max memory (respectively -Xms and -Xmx) to the same value to prevent heap
#    from resizing at runtime.
#
#sonar.search.javaOpts=-Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
#  -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 \
#  -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

# Same as previous property, but allows to not repeat all other settings like -Xmx
#sonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts=

# Elasticsearch port. Default is 9001. Use 0 to get a free port.
# This port must be private and must not be exposed to the Internet.
#sonar.search.port=9001


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# UPDATE CENTER

# Update Center requires an internet connection to request http://update.sonarsource.org
# It is enabled by default.
#sonar.updatecenter.activate=true

# HTTP proxy (default none)
#http.proxyHost=
#http.proxyPort=

# NT domain name if NTLM proxy is used
#http.auth.ntlm.domain=

# SOCKS proxy (default none)
#socksProxyHost=
#socksProxyPort=

# proxy authentication. The 2 following properties are used for HTTP and SOCKS proxies.
#http.proxyUser=
#http.proxyPassword=


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# LOGGING

# Level of logs. Supported values are INFO, DEBUG and TRACE
#sonar.log.level=INFO

# Path to log files. Can be absolute or relative to installation directory.
# Default is <installation home>/logs
#sonar.path.logs=logs

# Rolling policy of log files
#    - based on time if value starts with "time:", for example by day ("time:yyyy-MM-dd")
#      or by month ("time:yyyy-MM")
#    - based on size if value starts with "size:", for example "size:10MB"
#    - disabled if value is "none".  That needs logs to be managed by an external system like logrotate.
#sonar.log.rollingPolicy=time:yyyy-MM-dd

# Maximum number of files to keep if a rolling policy is enabled.
#    - maximum value is 20 on size rolling policy
#    - unlimited on time rolling policy. Set to zero to disable old file purging.
#sonar.log.maxFiles=7

# Access log is the list of all the HTTP requests received by server. If enabled, it is stored
# in the file {sonar.path.logs}/access.log. This file follows the same rolling policy as for
# sonar.log (see sonar.log.rollingPolicy and sonar.log.maxFiles).
#sonar.web.accessLogs.enable=true

# Format of access log. It is ignored if sonar.web.accessLogs.enable=false. Value is:
#    - "common" is the Common Log Format (shortcut for: %h %l %u %user %date "%r" %s %b)
#    - "combined" is another format widely recognized (shortcut for: %h %l %u [%t] "%r" %s %b "%i{Referer}" "%i{User-Agent}")
#    - else a custom pattern. See http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#AccessPatternLayout
#sonar.web.accessLogs.pattern=combined


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# OTHERS

# Delay in seconds between processing of notification queue. Default is 60 seconds.
#sonar.notifications.delay=60

# Paths to persistent data files (embedded database and search index) and temporary files.
# Can be absolute or relative to installation directory.
# Defaults are respectively <installation home>/data and <installation home>/temp
#sonar.path.data=data
#sonar.path.temp=temp


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# DEVELOPMENT - only for developers
# The following properties MUST NOT be used in production environments.

# Dev mode allows to reload web sources on changes and to restart server when new versions
# of plugins are deployed.
#sonar.web.dev=false

# Path to webapp sources for hot-reloading of Ruby on Rails, JS and CSS (only core,
# plugins not supported).
#sonar.web.dev.sources=/path/to/server/sonar-web/src/main/webapp

# Uncomment to enable the Elasticsearch HTTP connector, so that ES can be directly requested through
# http://lmenezes.com/elasticsearch-kopf/?location=http://localhost:9010
#sonar.search.httpPort=9010
```

Answer (score 1):

The default port is 9000. 
So if you want any port other than 9000, you need to uncomment the below line and specify exact port number that you want to choose. You can uncomment the below line and give the port as 9000 too. It does not harm.

```
sonar.web.port=9000
```

Can you pls let us know the url that you are typing in browser. It should be something like

```
http://yourhost:9000/
```

For more information, you can visit http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing

Answer (score 0):

Please check the port 9000 is enabled or not.
You can check it by using this command on linux machine

```
netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
```

9000 Port should be enable like given in below image:

[image]

After enable restart the sonarqube server and try to open in browser.